# WSO2 EMM Agent Root detected

Tags: android, root, wso2, wso2-iot

today i installed the WSO2 EMM Server as alternative to our existing mdm software.
My company is building her own Android Smartphones an Tablet-PCs with Stock Android 4.x.x.
I installed the Android EMM-Agent and got the information that my device is rooted.

> You are not allowed to enroll because your device is rooted

But there is no root on the phone.

So how can i say the agent that the device is not rooted?
Or should i talk to the developers?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue ...

You can workaround the problem by modifying the source of the agent in order to bypass the root test !

This is on the file Root.java, function isDeviceRooted(), just comment the three lines of test :

```
public boolean isDeviceRooted() { 
    // if (checkRootMethod3()){return true;}
    // if (checkRootMethod2()){return true;}
    // if (checkRootMethod1()){return true;}
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An another way is to analyze the way the agent find that your device is rooted ...

The code is the following :

```
/**
*Returns true if the OS build tags contains "test-keys"
*/
public boolean checkRootMethod1(){
    String buildTags = android.os.Build.TAGS;

    if (buildTags != null && buildTags.contains("test-keys")) {
        Log.e("ROOT CHECKER", "ROOT METHOD 1");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
/**
*Returns true if the device contains SuperUser.apk which is stored into the device in the rooting process
*/
public boolean checkRootMethod2(){
    try {
        File file = new File("/system/app/Superuser.apk");
        if (file.exists()) {
            Log.e("ROOT CHECKER", "ROOT METHOD 2");
            return true;

        }
    } catch (Exception e) { }

    return false;
}
/**
*Executes a shell command (superuser access with su binary) and returns true if the command succeeds
*/
public boolean checkRootMethod3() {
    if (new ExecShell().executeCommand(ExecShell.SHELL_CMD.check_su_binary) != null){
        Log.e("ROOT CHECKER", "ROOT METHOD 3");
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

So, there're 3 checks :

1. you have the chain "test-keys" on your Android buildTags !
2. you have the Superuser.apk on your device !
3. your device is really rooted because you can execute a shell command
   with superuser access !!!